# Сжать массив в строку с сохранением ключей

Tags: массивы, php, строки

Необходимо легко сжать массив в строку с сохранением ключей, и так же легко его распаковать эту строку в массив. Есть ли какие стандартные функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чувак, это называется сериализация/десериализация (функции в php: [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) / [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)), так же никто не запрещает использовать свои механизмы (например: xml или json). Это основа языка! Чем вам не угодил JSON? Что значит "глючит с UTF"?

Comment: Сойдет. Про недостаток json прокомментировал выше.

Answer (score 0):

JSON

```
json_encode(МАССИВ); //в строку JSON   
json_decode(СТРОКА_JSON); //в массив
```

Comment: Не подходит - глючит с UTF.

Comment: что именно глючит?

Comment: Происходит перевод кириллических символов формат \u*, что значительно увеличивает объём данных. Не вариант.

Comment: извини друг, но это не json глючит а ты не знаешь что такое unicode..
не устраивают мировые стандарты кодирования строк - предложи свой =)

Comment: Причем тут стандарты кодирования? Запись русских символов в unicode-представлении - это лишняя трата дискового пространства.